# Unable to install Tailwindcss into Rails 6

Tags: webpacker, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently trying to install Tailwind into a rails 6 application via Webpack but after following the docs the styles are not being applied to a view template as shown in the image. I have Tailwind v1.0.3. I also tried to upgrade Webpack to v4 so not sure if it's something due to that.

[image]

I have the following files:

javascript/css/application.css

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

My packs/application.js looks as follow:

```
require("stylesheets/application.scss")
```

And my /postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    })
  ]
}
```

I can also see from the packaje.json file that Tailwind was in fact installed.

```
{
  "name": "artsy_space",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "3.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-loader": "14.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2"
  }
}
```

and the application.html.erb

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>ArtsySpace</title>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= csp_meta_tag %>

        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'stylesheets', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
      </head>

      <body>
          <p class="alert alert-error">
            <%= flash[:alert] %>
          </p>

          <p class="alert alert-info">
            <%= flash[:notice] %>
          </p>
        <%= yield %>
      </body>
    </html>

H
```

ere is a [link to a PR](https://github.com/theasteve/artsy_space/tree/tailwind) in the repo.

Any idea what might it be?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you might be requiring the wrong directory. Try changing:

```
require("stylesheets/application.scss")
```

to:

```
require("css/application.css")
```

Also, note that you're requiring a .scss file but it looks like the actual file is .css?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your javascript/packs/application.js file

`require("stylesheets/application.scss")`

Everything else looks correct.

I'm also assuming you ran `yarn add tailwindcss` in your console.

If adding that file doesn't work, try running `bin/webpack` in your console.

If there are any error messages, they will help you debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me is importing manually tailwind file into the `application.js` file.

`require("./../../assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css")`

and then running `rails assets:clobber`